# How to send an image as a child using a React Portal?

Tags: reactjs, image, typescript

I want to display a few images in a new window on the click of a button. These images will be retrieved from a database with other data.

I am using typescript and React-Redux. I've followed mainly the example of how to use React-Portals posted from David Gilbertson [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202).

```js
import PopupWindow from "./PopupWindow";
import Pizza from '../../../Images/pizza.jpg'

class Assessment extends React.Component<Props, any> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isImagesOpen: false,
            imageOne: Pizza
        };

        this.togglePopupWindow = this.togglePopupWindow.bind(this);
        this.closePopupWindow = this.closePopupWindow.bind(this);
    }

    // switch the toggle
    togglePopupWindow() {
        let flip = !this.state.isImagesOpen;
        this.setState({ isImagesOpen: flip });
    }

    // explicitly close the window
    closePopupWindow() {
        this.setState({ isImagesOpen: false });
    }

render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                    ...
                       // image here displays fine 
                       <div>
                           <img src={this.state.imageOne} alt="Pizza" />
                       </div>
                        <button onClick={ this.togglePopupWindow } >
                            Click Me!
                        </button>
                        {
                            this.state.isImagesOpen && (
                                <PopupWindow closePopupWindow={this.closePopupWindow}>
                                    //image here (same as above) does not show in the window
                                    <img src={this.state.imageOne} alt="Pizza" />
                                    <div>The Variant Images!</div>
                                </PopupWindow> )
                        }
                    ...
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
```

The image that is being sent to the portal does not display (the alt text displays). The same image displays fine when rendered by the Assessment Component and not via the Portal (Popup) component.

I could provide the code being used for the Popup window but it is similar to the link provided and the window itself works fine.

Ultimately, the image will not be a static import but one of several images that is retrieved from a database and needed to be displayed in a separate window to task being performed in the main window.

Comment: check the file path of image, thats where the problem is.

Comment: try    <img src={require('../../../Images/pizza.jpg)} />
make sure that the path is valid to component

Comment: here is example  where I am showing image in portal window. check https://codepen.io/kaiser_07/pen/VwZRJqw

Comment: @Kais I am just failing to see how what you've done is different from mine. At first I noticed you had hard-coded the image in the popup window components state. but I removed that in your code pen and your image still displayed, meaning it must be being passed through. I also changed my image path from a relative path to an absolute path and it made no difference.

Comment: @Kais Using a web link image ( as you have ) and not one with a source path in my project works fine. Since the image source will end up being a web link, it turns out the inability for me to use a project path doesn't actually matter. Not really sure how I can mark your comment as an accepted answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: @TrentRoss I have now updated code here with project image source used. check https://codesandbox.io/s/portal-image-mo4do